# Google Analytics - no hits notification - automatically advise?

Tags: google-analytics

We have a website that collects Google Analytics data and the GA key is stored in a CMS.

We recently had a scenario where someone accidentally deleted the GA key from the CMS system. It took 2 days for someone to notice the Analytics page was now showing the "No hits" notification

Is there anywhere in Google/Analytics where you can have the notifications automatically notify the email address that a notification is now live?

Answer (score 1):

## Google Analytics custom alerts

You can set up a Google Analytics' custom alert to do this. Keep in mind, however, that this isn't a "realtime" alerting system. Alerts are processed at the end of the day (PST) and then sent to you.

To set up an alert:

- Go to **Customization > Custom Alerts**
- Click the **Manage custom alerts** button
- Click on **+ NEW ALERT**
- Use the following settings:

  - **Alert name:** No hits alert
  - **Apply to:**
  - **Period:** Day
  - **Send me an email:** Tick & then add your email address
  - **Alert Conditions**

    - **This applies to:** All Traffic
    - **Alert me when:** Sessions
    - **Condition**: Is less than
    - **Value:** 1
- Click on **Save Alert**